# Apply a list to a summation expression

Tags: summation

I've gotten unexpected (at least to my novice eyes) application of a list of values to a `Sum` expression where the variable for imax is also used in the expression summed. For example:

```
n={10,100,1000,10000}

N[Sum[(i+1)/n^2,{i,1,n}]]
```

yields:

> ```
> {{0.65, 51.5, 5015., 500150.}, {0.0065, 0.515, 50.15,5001.5}, 
> {0.000065, 0.00515, 0.5015, 50.015}, {6.5*10^-7, 0.0000515,0.005015, 0.50015}}
> ```

when I was expecting:

```
{0.65, 0.515, 0.5015, 0.50015}
```

The two workarounds I've found to get my expected solution were to

(1) create a function for the summation and `SetAttributes` to `Listable`, eg.

```
f[x_]:=N[Sum[(i+1)/n^2,{i,1,n}]];
SetAttributes[f,Listable]
```

or

(2) first evaluate the expression to be summed symbolically, then apply the list

```
b=Sum[(i+1)/n^2,{i,1,n}]

(3 + n)/(2 n)

n={10,100,1000,10000}

N[b]
```

> ```
> {0.65, 0.515, 0.5015, 0.50015}
> ```

Is it normal for *Mathematica* to apply the list as initially shown?  If so, why, and is there a better way to achieve my solution than the two ways I've found?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior. Try to write `1/{1,2,3,4,5}` and see what the result is. Then try `{1,2,3,4,5}+{6,7,8,9,10}`. These two examples show why the result is what it is in your care.

Comment: @Pickett Thanks for the response.  However, both your examples give me the response I expect, applying each value in the list once.  But applying a list to the Sum function seems to iterate the list values across the Sum function.  It's not clear to me why it's doing that.

Comment: @Shutao Tang Thanks for the answer, particularly showing the use of the Tr function.

Comment: @BCott, You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Map` function directly:

```
f[n_] := N[Sum[(i + 1)/n^2, {i, 1, n}]];
n= {10, 100, 1000, 10000};
f /@ n(**or Map[f, n])
```

> ```
> {0.65, 0.515, 0.5015, 0.50015}
> ```

Or

```
Tr[
  N[Sum[(i+1)/n^2,{i,1,n}]],List]
```

> ```
> {0.65, 0.515, 0.5015, 0.50015}
> ```